# My deleted media exists jet

Tags: uploads, media-library

I've a problem with my wordpress theme. I deleted some media files (some img) and it's appearing in my Media section (in my wp-admin) without thumbnail, but it's like the file exist.

I'm looking in the database and deleted all the data in wp_postmeta but isn't work.

My files don't exists in uploads folder, database...but appear in my Media secction and can't be removed.

What can be the problem??

I see when try to put a post thumbnail this error (in wp-admin zone):

```
undefined is not a function in ajax.js:259
```

It's very strange... :S

Comment: Does this still happen, after you [disabled all plugins and switched to one of the Twenty* themes?](http://i.imgur.com/wScmw.png) Please follow the linked process to identify the conflicting plugin or theme.

Comment: Yes, I disabled my theme and disabled the plugins but I've the same problem

Comment: Try to reinstall WordPress (you can use the updater from the Dashboard to do so). Does the problem persist?

Answer (score 0):

I founded the solution... all it's a problem with a JS function called "slideUp" in my ajax.js (ajax's functions for my front-end site)

I don't know the reason, but when I try to upload or a media file, Wordpress try to execute this function. I change his name and the "$" for "jQuery" and now it's works correctly.

Thanks for the help!